# How to get required Contact display name based on phone number in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am working on react-native. I want to get Contact display name based on the phone number from his/her phone Contacts.
I am using below code. It is giving me the error. Can any suggest correct APIs or code?

```
 Contacts.searchContacts( "ABC", (error, contacts) =>  {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
        else {
          console.log(contacts);
        }
      });
```

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [react-native-contacts](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts), it doesn't look like they have a "searchContacts" function in their API. I would recommend using "getContactsMatchingString" (string, callback) - where the string is any string to match a name (first, middle, family)

```
{
  recordID: '6b2237ee0df85980',
  company: "",
  emailAddresses: [{
    label: "work",
    email: "carl-jung@example.com",
  }],
  familyName: "Jung",
  givenName: "Carl",
  jobTitle: "",
  note: 'some text',
  urlAddresses: [{
    label: "home",
    url: "www.jung.com",
  }],
  middleName: "",
  phoneNumbers: [{
    label: "mobile",
    number: "(555) 555-5555",
  }],
  hasThumbnail: true,
  thumbnailPath: 'content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/3',
  postalAddresses: [
    {
      street: '123 Fake Street',
      city: 'Sample City',
      state: 'CA',
      region: 'CA',
      postCode: '90210',
      country: 'USA',
      label: 'home'
    }
  ],
  birthday: {"year": 1988, "month": 0, "day": 1 }
}
```

Comment: hi vincent vella, Thanks for can it possible to get name from number

Comment: Yes, I've edited my original post to show the callback format of the contacts received. @user1915370